# Trying to refactor code for a static site using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-site

I am doing an assignment right now for class. It involves refactoring python code to generate static site pages. I am in the phase where I am trying to refactor the code for my site generator and it involves a for loop that does templating of the site. My instructor tells me that I have to delete some repeating lines and replace them with a single copy for the for loop. I would very much appreciate the help on this as i am tackling this for the first time. I recognize the repeating instances but I don't know how to properly structure them in code.

Here's my code so far:

```
def main():
    print('building static site')
    top_html = open('templates/top.html').read()
    bottom_html = open('templates/bottom.html').read()
    middle_html = open('content/index.html').read()
    combined_html = top_html + middle_html + bottom_html
    open('docs/index.html', 'w+').write(combined_html)

    print('building static site')
    top_html = open('templates/top.html').read()
    bottom_html = open('templates/bottom.html').read()
    middle_html = open('content/projects.html').read()
    combined_html = top_html + middle_html + bottom_html
    open('docs/projects.html', 'w+').write(combined_html)

    print('building static site')
    top_html = open('templates/top.html').read()
    bottom_html = open('templates/bottom.html').read()
    middle_html = open('content/contact.html').read()
    combined_html = top_html + middle_html + bottom_html
    open('docs/contact.html', 'w+').write(combined_html)

    for page in pages:
        filename = page['filename']
        print('the filename that we want to read in:', filename)
main()
```

Comment: Hello! What you want to do is to create a function to get rid of the repetitions. Leave what is constant (for example`print('building static site')`) and replace what is not with a variable. In your case, you could use a variable where there is "index", "projects", and "contact".

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: I am trying to refactor the code the makes the sites and making the code less repetitive by it in a function that makes sense.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to make the code block display correctly. (Before, the indentation didn't show and the `main()` call at the end was displayed as not code.) Please check whether everything is still correct and [edit] your question if needed.

Comment: @JensenDavid ***" refactor the code ... less repetitive by it in a function"***: What is stoping you to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are 3 sections of this format which all just write to different places. This is bad practice because if you want to change one, you have to remember to change it in 3 different places.

```
print('building static site')
top_html = open('templates/top.html').read()
bottom_html = open('templates/bottom.html').read()
middle_html = open('content/projects.html').read()
combined_html = top_html + middle_html + bottom_html
open('docs/projects.html', 'w+').write(combined_html)
```

You could change this to a function which takes the name of the thing to build (`contacts` in this case) and then substitutes it where necessary.

```
def build_site(file_name):
    print('building static site')
    top_html = open('templates/top.html').read()
    bottom_html = open('templates/bottom.html').read()
    middle_html = open(f'content/{file_name}').read()
    combined_html = top_html + middle_html + bottom_html
    open(f'docs/{file_name}', 'w+').write(combined_html)
```

Notice that `projects.html` has been replaced with `file_name` that we pass into the function.

This makes the main function go down to:

```
def main():
    build_site('index.html')
    build_site('projects.html')
    build_site('contact.html')

    for page in pages:
        filename = page['filename']
        print('the filename that we want to read in:', filename)
```

All of the sites we are building here end `.html`. We could have put this in the `build_site()` function but that limits your directories to only containing files ending `.html`. To go a step further we could use a loop now for each of the different pages.

```
def main():
    for site_name in ('index', 'projects', 'contact'):
        build_site(f'{site_name}.html')
    for page in pages:
        filename = page['filename']
        print('the filename that we want to read in:', filename)
```

---

#### Further Improvements

Here are some further improvements I would make.

1. When you do `open(...).read()` you're failing to close the file, so it just hangs around until it gets cleaned up. You could create a new function for this using a *context manager* so the file is automatically closed.

```
def read_content(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Then change `build_site` to have:

```
top_html = read_content('templates/top.html')
bottom_html = read_content('templates/bottom.html')
middle_html = read_content('content/projects.html')
```

I'd do a similar thing for writing file, but because it only happens once, I wouldn't create a function.

```
...
with open(f'docs/{file_name}', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(combined_html)
...
```

2. I would put the print statement outside the function (but inside the for loop) as I don't like printing stuff in functions that do things. I'd also make it print out what was being built.

```
# delete print(...) in build_site(file_name)
# then

def main():
    for site_name in ('index', 'projects', 'contact'):
        print(f'Building static site: {site_name}')
        build_site(f'{site_name}.html')
    ...
```